# Why there is no error after excluding standard library?

Tags: c, header-files

As a beginner in C I was experimenting something, so I excluded the standard library `<stdio.h>` and still there is no error. Can someone explain it?

Here is the sample code:

```
main()
{
    printf("hello, world!\n");
}
```

This program is working same with or without library. Why?

Comment: Did you see the warning?

Comment: there is no warning in build log.

Comment: Then you should use all the compiler flags to enable the warnings...

Comment: There is an error, it's just that your compiler didn't tell you about it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR -- You're excluding the header file, not the standard library.

---

If you exclude the header file where the function is having a forward declaration, you'll receive a warning for sure mentioning the "implicit declaration" of the function.

In that case, (invalid as per the latest standards), the function will be assumed to return `int` and no check on the number of parameters passed will be there.

However, by default, the generated object file from your source is linked with the default C library `libc` which has the function definition present. In this case, the function return type matches the *implicit* case, so linker happily links the object files together.

So, it successfully finishes the linking and *works same*.

That said, `main()` should be `int main(void)`, at least to conform to the standards.

Comment: The code causes UB by calling a variadic function without a prototype (even in C89), it'd be good if your answer mentioned this .   It may very well not "work same"

Comment: @M.M Matt sir, I don't have a copy of C89, so I did not add that part. Anyways, I mentioned _invalid_ as this is non-standard. I have looked in 6.5.2.2, C11, but did not get the exact quote to support the UB. Can you  please share your view?

Comment: @M.M: Calling a variadic function without a visible prototype (i.e., either without a declaration or with a declaration that uses empty parentheses) has undefined behavior starting with C89/C90. In addition, calling *any* function without a visible declaration (which may or may not be a prototype) is a constraint violation in C99 and later; C99 dropped the "implicit `int`" rule.

Comment: @M.M: On the other hand, pre-ANSI C didn't have prototypes, and `printf` was part of the standard library from time immemorial, so breaking unprototyped `printf` calls would have broken existing code. C89 made such a call UB, but almost all compilers support them anyway. (If there's a compiler where it doesn't work, I'd be interested in hearing about it.)

Comment: These days compilers optimize printf, e.g. using registers for passing the first few parameters even tho it's a variadic function, it's possible to foresee something going wrong there if lack of declaration causes the compiler to not do both ends of that optimization

Answer (score 1):

While it is recommended to include the standard header files when appropriate, it is not necessarily required.  The default return value for a function is int (which you ignore in your code and is perfectly allowable).  The notion of function prototypes was added to the language well after there was a substantial body of existing programs and so in order to not break them, function prototypes are optional and the default is to have no prototype which means there is no compiler validation that the types of arguments are correct.

Your program is able to link properly against the standard library and execute correctly.

"Hello World!" is a very simple program, so it would be a mistake to rely on this behavior for anything substantial.

Comment: Calling a variadic function without a prototype causes undefined behaviour. The code's would only be correct for a limited subset of possible functions (e.g. ones that take fixed number of int argument and return int).

Comment: As of the 1999 ISO C standard, calling a function with no visible declaration (variadic or not) is a *constraint violation*, requiring a diagnostic. In the earlier 1989/1990 standard, it was not. Many compilers do not fully conform to the current standard by default. A conforming C99 or C11 compiler must at least issue a diagnostic (possibly a non-fatal warning) for the code in the question.